# Nested query and retrieve parent attributes for child filter

Tags: solr, subquery, solr5

I was going through Yonik's [blog](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/).
I am using solr 5.3.0 and I have a scenario which I am trying to solve.
Any help will be appreciated.

Generalizing Yonik's example:

Old Document:

```
{
  product_name : "Awesome T-Shirt",
  category : "Clothing",
  color : [ "Red", "Blue"],
  size : [ "L", "M", "XL" ]
}
```

Parent:

```
{
  product_name : "Awesome T-Shirt",
  category : "Clothing",
}
```

Nested Children:

```
{
  color : "Red",
  size : "L",
  quantity: 2
}
{
  color : "Blue",
  size : "M",
  quantity: 3
}
{
  color : "Blue",
  size : "L",
  quantity: 0
}
{
  color : "Red",
  size : "L",
  quantity: 0
}
{
  color : "Red",
  size : "XL",
  quantity: 1
}
```

Counting some scenarios:
1) If I put filter for color:Red and size:L I get the children documents only. Is that possible to get the parent fields on response (Since I have multiple products with color:Red and size:L).

2) If I search for color:Red and quantity greater than 0, I get multiple documents while this search is just to check if item in red color is available. Though group by is a work around, is there any other way.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get `parent documents` with `child documents` I'd do this:

```
/select?q=id:<parent id>
&fq=type:<parent type>
&fl=*,[child parentFilter="type:<parent type>" limit=10]
```

it will return a structure like this:

```
{
"type":"<parent type>",
....
"_childDocuments_":[{
<doc>..</doc>
...
<doc>..</doc>
}]
}
```

child document count is limited with `limit=10` you can change that of course but default is 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Solr's block join parsers will get you what you need:

[Block join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Though I have given a try to it but I am not getting the desired result. Can you give an example of query for above scenario?